# Prove that $f$ has only one maximum point and only one minimum point and find them.

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, be differentiable  (twice) such that:

$$ \sin(f(x))+2f(x)= 2x^3-9x^2+12x $$ for each $x$.

prove that $f$ has only one maximum point and only one minimum point and find them.

SOLUTION ATTEMPT: I defined a new function called $G(x)$.
$G(x)=\sin(f(x))+2f(x) - 2x^3+9x^2-12x$.

I'm trying from here to use Roll's Theorem or Intermediate value theorem. but couldn't because $f(x)$ is inside another function in this case, and  somehow its confusing. I know also that for a maximum point for example called $x_0$ , $f^\prime(x_0)=0$. and also $f^\prime$ should change sign before and after $x_0$, suggesting that $f$ is continuous and differentiable near $x_0$. 
and suggestion for how to begin?

I tried to differentiate both sides and got an expression for $f^\prime$, and derived the expression and made it equal to the $f^\prime$$^\prime$  that I get by deffirentiating both sides again and finally got:

$$\sin(f(x)) \cdot f^\prime(x)(cos(f(x))+2)=\sin(f(x)) \cdot f^\prime(x) \cdot (6x^2-18x+12)$$
now how do I continue from here?

Comment: Good attempt, but your new function $G(x)$ is equal to $0$ everywhere (do you see why?).

Comment: oops, so I guess its not a good attempt afterall.

Comment: Well, you have to try *something* if you ever hope to solve the problem.  And you did try something (even though it ended up not being correct).  So kudos to you!

Comment: Have you tried differentiating both sides of the equation with respect to $x$?  You should actually be able to differentiate both sides twice since $f$ is twice differentiable.  It might lead somewhere

Comment: I tried to deffirentiate $G(x)$ twice which is the same thing almost if I rearrange the sums. I will think if I can use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Differentiating both sides,

$$\cos(f(x))\cdot f'(x)+2f'(x) = 6x^2-18x+12$$
$$\Rightarrow f'(x) = \frac{6x^2-18x+12}{\cos(f(x))+2}$$

Comment: Can you take a look at my edit?

Comment: @F1sargyan If you notice in this answer, Daniel got a fraction which equals $f'(x)$.  Now, first of all, this expression for $f'(x)$ exists everywhere since the denominator is never $0$.  Also, at a maximum or minimum, $f'(x) = 0$, right?  So if $f$ has any maximum or minimum, it will be when $f'(x) = 0$, i.e., when this fraction expression equals $0$.  But a fraction is $0$ only when the numerator equals $0$, so we get that $f$ has a maximum or minimum when $6x^{2} - 18x + 12 = 0$.  Solving this equation gives two values for $x$.

Comment: @F1sargyan But  we still don't know which one is a max or which one is a min.  Remember that if $y$ is a max, then $f''(y) > 0$, and if $y$ is a min, then $f''(y) < 0$.  So you will need to find an expression for $f''(x)$ in the same way as we found an expression for $f'(x)$ (try differentiating both sides of the expression above again): then plug in the values we got to see when $f''(x) > 0$ and when $f''(x) < 0$.

Comment: Nice! Thanks.. This helped alot

Comment: @F1sargyan Sorry, I think I was mistaken.  A max gives $f''(x) < 0$ and a min gives $f''(x) > 0$.